# [ROS2 foxy] Python launch argument scope when nesting launch files

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tldr is can you scope launch arguments in the python launch system when using `IncludeLaunchDescription`?

Assume we have a base python launch file (`base_launch.py`, referred to as *base*) that includes another python launch file (`ext_launch.py`, referred to as *ext*). The *base* has an argument `arg1` that it may use and pass on to one or more included launch files. *Ext* also has an argument of the same name. I print the *base* argument, include *ext* which also print its argument, and then again print the argument in *base*. The output from this shows that changes to the arguments value in *ext* also changes the arguments value in *base*.

Is there any way to not overwrite arguments of the same name (i.e. assign arguments with scope)? Or is there a different design pattern that should be followed?

**base_launch.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, LogInfo, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, ThisLaunchFileDir

def generate_launch_description():
  arg1 = LaunchConfiguration('arg1')

  return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
      'arg1',
      default_value='Internal_Arg',
      description='Argument'
    ),

    LogInfo(msg=['Internal Arg (before): ', arg1]),

    IncludeLaunchDescription(
      PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(),'/ext_launch.py']),
      launch_arguments={
        'arg1': 'External_Arg_Mod'
      }.items()
    ),

    LogInfo(msg=['Internal Arg (after): ', arg1]),

  ])
```

**ext_launch.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import LogInfo, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

def generate_launch_description():
  arg1 = LaunchConfiguration('arg1')

  return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
      'arg1',
      default_value='External_Arg',
      description='Argument'
    ),

    LogInfo(msg=['External Arg: ', arg1])
  ])
```

**Output:**

```
[INFO] [launch.user]: Internal Arg (before): Internal_Arg
[INFO] [launch.user]: External Arg: External_Arg_Mod
[INFO] [launch.user]: Internal Arg (after): External_Arg_Mod
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377776/%5Bros2-foxy%5D-python-launch-argument-scope-when-nesting-launch-files/) by [djchopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/74140/djchopp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2021-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [the `GroupAction` action](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/launch/actions/group_action.py). From its docstring:

> Action that yields other actions, optionally scoping launch configurations.
>
> This action is used to nest other actions without including a separate
> launch description, while also optionally having a condition (like all
> other actions), scoping launch configurations, and/or declaring launch
> configurations for just the group and its yielded actions.

You can wrap the inclusion of  *ext* in a group action to achieve the scoping you want:

```
GroupAction([
    IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(),'/ext_launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={
            'arg1': 'External_Arg_Mod'
        }.items()
    )
]),
```

With that, running `ros2 launch launch_test base_launch.py` gives:

```
[INFO] [launch.user]: Internal Arg (before): Internal_Arg
[INFO] [launch.user]: External Arg: External_Arg_Mod
[INFO] [launch.user]: Internal Arg (after): Internal_Arg
```

[Internally the scoping works](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/3a5c9df2e384271637ac029f48f020b7916498d6/launch/launch/actions/group_action.py#L81-L86) by using the `PushLaunchConfigurations` and `PopLaunchConfigurations` actions:

```
        if self.__scoped:
            self.__actions_to_return = [
                PushLaunchConfigurations(),
                *self.__actions_to_return,
                PopLaunchConfigurations()
            ]
```

So you may also be able to surround the include with those in your own launch file if you feel that using `GroupAction` around a single action is less nice.

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2